# invoke_result_t<> not matching lambda with a reference parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Using a function that accepts templated functions works great when the type is either an rvalue reference or has no reference, but as soon as I make it an lvalue reference it breaks.

Note that V is currently unused here, but it still fails to compile anyways regardless of whether it's used or not.

```
using namespace std;

template <typename F, typename V = std::invoke_result_t<F, string>>
void func(F f) {
    std::vector<string> v = { "a", "b", "c" };
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
}

int main() {
    func([](string s) { return s.length(); });         // Good
    // func([](string& s) { return s.length(); });     // Bad
    func([](const string& s) { return s.length(); });  // Good
}
```

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:18:46: error: no matching function for call to 'func(main()::)'
>
> ```
>  func([](string& s) { return s.length(); });
>
>                                           ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:11:6: note: candidate: 'template void func(F)'
>
> ```
>   void func(F f) {
>
>        ^~~~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:11:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

I can't do something like

```
std::invoke_result_t<F, string&>
```

and I couldn't do something like

```
std::invoke_result_t<F, std::add_lvalue_reference_t<string>>
```

The last one was a shot in the dark. My template knowledge is not that great. I've been searching around on here and on various blogs/google/etc, haven't had much success.

Comment: To catch all cases, you can try with `std::invoke_result_t<F, string const &>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::invoke_result_t<F, string>
```

this means passing `F` a `string` rvalue.  And you cannot if `F` takes an lvalue reference.

> I can't do something like
>
> ```
>  std::invoke_result_t<F, string&>
> ```

well yes you can.  Do that if you want to know what the result of calling it with a non-const lvalue is.

At your point of use in your sample code, you pass it an lvalue.  The `string&&` overload does not work.

Comment: How can I make it so it can accept any function? Right now if I do `string` or `string&` or `string&&` it changes the type of lambda that can be given, but I want it to be able to support any type. Is it possible to have all of them accepted by one function? I looked into the STL for examples but I can't understand why it works but mine doesn't.

Comment: @Water How are you going to *call* the function you pass in?  There are very few ways to call a function in a way that both `string&&` and `string&` arguments are allowed, and of those, almost all of them are nonsense.  I'm unaware of a non-broken STL implementation that ever accepts both.  `string&&` should *only* bind to rvalues, and `string&` to lvalues, and an argument shouldn't be both.

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own `std::for_each` as a learning exercise, so I want it to be called with anything, as in the user can pass a lambda that allows mutation through only an lvalue, or a function that uses a const lvalue reference so they don't have any copying happening during the loop but do want to modify it, or even by value if the user wants. Example of the STL accepting any kind of function, including a non-const lvalue reference: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84951914356ed003 (whereas mine stops working when I do an lvalue reference). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Water Your example code **doesn't accept `int&&`**.  You even commented out the line where you tried to pass that in.  That matches what happens when you do ... *exactly what I say* in my answer.  So I'm utterly confused what is confusing to you.  "anything" is either vague or a lie: do you want your function to be called with a chicken you see in your neighbors yard?  Probably not.  You are going to write code that calls that function, presumably.  What are you missing: **How are you going to call the function you pass in?**  You are missing an answer to that.

Comment: Putting an rvalue reference was a bad idea on my part since I don't plan on using any rvalues, but I'd still like it to accept it (and then complain to the user if it fails). However as I wanted in my OP, I'd like to be able to pass a lambda to a function that works for either an lvalue reference, a const lvalue reference, or just a regular value. `std::for_each` makes it work somehow, so I'm doing something wrong that the standard library doesn't. For how it's called: I'm not calling it, I'm passing it to a `std::` library function that calls it (ex: for_each).

Comment: If it helps make it more clear, I just edited the main post to remove the rvalue reference from it. My question is: How would you make it so all 3 lambdas work with `func`? What template magic must I do to make it accept all 3 of them?

Comment: @water And I already answered your question.  `string&`.  That means "pass a lvalue of type `string`".  I, again, do not understand why anything is confusing.  Use `std::invoke_result_t<F, string&>`.  It will work.  I have no idea why you aren't using it.  I have no idea why my instructions to use it are confusing to you.  Please stop being confused, and just do it.